# Can Hotwire be implemented on Rails app that already has Angular front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, frontend, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I have a RoR app with Angular and I want to make a mobile app of it. I have been searching and it seems Hotwire Turbo might be a good option for a few reasons.

In order to use Hotwire in my current project, is it possible to use it with my current Angular front end?

If not, what would be the way to go, rewrite all the front end with Hotwire? Any particular suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself if the complete Frontend is written in Angular?
If so, how does it work: do you have Rails views that call a Angular component or is the frontend a completely separate thing?

If its component style, it's more easy realistic to slowly introduce Hotwire.

Comment: Thanks Leon! By completely separate you mean having it in a different repo?

If it was component style, do you know any good resource that shows how to start introducing Hotwire? (Or any suggestions on how to start the process)